# How to set empty date field to a default date

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

How do I set a default value for an empty date field. This is what i have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
request.GET.get('received_date', '1/1/2000')
```

Comment: You should explain more about your problem and whats the problem with your code. the code is simple and it will replace `1/1/2000` if the value for `received_date` is `None` which is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

If you want to define your default date in the view:

```
received_date = request.GET.get('received_date')
if not received_date or received_date == None:
    received_date = '1/1/2000'
```

If you want to define your default date in the model :

```
received_date = models.DateField(default='01/01/2000', blank=True)
```

Comment: awesome. thank you. I had it right for the model. needed it for the view

Answer (score 0):

You can set in model definition somewhat like below

`date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True)`

Answer (score 0):

That will work if you convert it to a datetime object and then pass it to your model.

```
date = request.GET.get('received_date', '1/1/2000')

date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```